# Image source from local IP is not showing in Xamarin.Forms Image or FFImage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

We have a local application (client/server) and the WebAPI and images are hosted in our local IIS server.

When setting the source of FFImage or the Image control in Xamarin.Forms
i.e `source="http://192.168.200.248/TTT012020305200.jpg"`
The image is not showing

But when setting the source 
i.e. `source="http://www.randomdomain.com/randomimage.jpg"` 
The image is showing

That's just an example by the way, the original source is bounded to a Model and property.
i.e source="{Binding Model.ImageProperty}"

Is there a work around on this?

Comment: Check if you can load the image on a browser on the device using the i.p. address.  I've had lots of problems with the work network not allowing devices to see each other - it's fine going out to the web, but the mobile phone can't see my dev box because of network rules.

Comment: @GregHNZ Yes, the images are loading in the browser. PC and in Mobile device browsers

Comment: do you have your app configured to allow non-https requests?

Comment: for some reason, I changed the HttpClient Implementatio to "Managed" and it's working now.